# packaging a second-level sub-directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, setup.py

I have this project architecture and I want to make `my_package` pip installable. The project doesn't only contain stuff to package but also simple scripts (the quick and dirty kind) and over things that are important in my project but not for the package (external data for example).

```
my_project
├── code
│   ├── data          #<-- I don't want to package this
│   │   └── make_dataset.py
│   ├── script        #<-- I don't want to package this
│   │   └── make_experiment.py
│   └── my_package    #<-- This is the module I want to package
│       ├── core.py
│       ├── utils.py
│       └── __init__.py
├── data
│   └── some_data.txt
├── references
│   └── reference_paper.pdf
├── reports
│   └── report.tex
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├── requirements.txt
└── setup.py
```

I would like the `setup.py` file to be in the top-level directory so that people can do the usual

```
git clone gitinstance.com/my_project
cd my_project
pip install .
```

and get `my_package` module installed in their environment so they can already do `python -c import my_package; print(my_package.__version__)` and it works.

The question is: **How can I make `my_package` pip-installable without putting `setup.py` inside the `code` directory?**

Usually, the `setup.py` would look like this:

```
from setuptools import find_packages, setup

setup(
    name='my_package',
    packages=find_packages(),
    version='0.1.0',
    description='Research project',
    author='Name',
    license='MIT',
)
```

But it wouldn't work here because `setup.py` can't find `my_package`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[I found an example in the documentation of setuptools that more or less fit my use-case.](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#find-namespace-packages)

The solution is in the `packages` and `package_dir` arguments of the `setup` function that allows to specify where to find the packages to install. This is usually hidden because it defaults to the current working directory.

In my simple case, the `setup.py` transforms to:

```
from setuptools import find_packages, setup

setup(
    name='my_package',
    packages=find_packages(where="code"),
    package_dir={'': "code"},
    version='0.1.0',
    description='Research project',
    author='Name',
    license='MIT',
)
```